# Size of nuts for body mounting bolts on an 2000 model Isuzu TFR / Holden Rodeo

Tags: holden, isuzu

I lost the nuts off the body mounting bolts on a 2000 model Holden Rodeo / Isuzu TF. I've been looking through workshop manuals and searching but I can't seem to find what size nuts I need to go back on these bolts. The workshop manual shows the positions and torque specifications but doesn't seem to identify the size of the nut or bolt so I can find the appropriate size nuts.

Can anyone tell me how to identify the right size for these?

Answer (score 1):

I would source bolts that closely fit the holes they will go into.

Once you have the correct diameter bolts then you will have the "normal" nut or hexagon sizes. Use washers as necessary and torque to spec.